# Datetimeoffset? maps to Datetime2 Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use Entity Framework code first approach. Whenever I create a property with type Datetimeoffset in my class, a column with type Datetime2 will get generated in the corresponding table. I wish to have a column of type Datetimeoffset (with time zone) and precision 2. What should my property type be in c# in order to achieve that?

I have also noticed that it is actually DateTimeOffset? that maps to Datetime2 in DB, whereas DateTimeOffset (Not nullable) maps into Datetimeoffset(7) . Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You can use Fluent API and add column type for property mapping

Comment: That seems like a good workaround. Can you provide a sample of how to implement that globally?

Comment: I don't know about your DbContext and entities definitions but you can override OnModelCreating method in DbContext and add something like this: entity.Property(p => p.Date).HasColumnType("Datetime2");